# i have a problem when i try to join an additional domain controller to a domain of DC , cant find the domain

Tags: networking, azure-active-directory, active-directory, domaincontroller

I can't make the ADC join the domain.
I have set the DNS entries for DC and ADC to the same IP address.

[image: Info]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of abbreviations, so I'm not 100% sure what exactly your problem is.

There's always a few things you can check, though:

1. Make sure that the joining machine can resolve your domain successfully, i.e. entering `nslookup the.domain` in a command shell should return the IP address of the existing domain controller.

If it succeeds, but you still cannot join,

2. Make sure that the relevant ports for a domain controller are reachable from the joining machine, the most important being 53/tcp, 53/udp, 88/udp, 135/tcp, 445/tcp, and 1024-65535/tcp. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/config-firewall-for-ad-domains-and-trusts)

Comment: I change the SID for this machine

Comment: I put the DNS IP for the additional DC same as the DNS of primary Domain controller

Comment: the error "the server is not operational"

Comment: there is no connection between DC and add DC when i ping

Comment: the solution : there is no connection between the machines because of the virtual machine is NAT adapter and to ping it should be a Bridged